# Flutter: the operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get the nested object values? `print(_user.userLocation()['location']);` returns `{country: Eesti, city: Tallin}`

So, I tried with `_user.userLocation()['location']['city']` to get the value `Tallinn`. However, I am getting

`The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.`

`print(_user.userLocation())` and  `print(_user.location().runtimeType);` returns

```
location: {
   country: Eesti,
   city: Tallinn,
}

flutter: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
```

I tried to set a variable to `var a = _user.location()['location']` and then `a['city']`. However, this is not working as well.

Comment: please check the answer that i added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try like this,

```
var a = _user.userLocation() as Map;
print(a['location]['city']);
```

I issue here is dart's `type inference` is not able to identify the type automatically.So that it gives the error.But the above solution should work

Comment: Is there any way that I can set `as Map;` from the beginning? I am using Get and `final UserInfoController _userInfoController = Get.find();`, If it is possible, I want to state it when I import them at the top.